# Bundle returns long instead of Parcelable

Tags: java, android, bundle

In `activityA` I have a `listview`, each item of which is a custom `Parcelable` object. On `listViewItemClick` I show a `fragment` with two arguments, which I put in `bundle` with this method:

```
public void openFragment(CustomParcelable parcelableObject, long objectID) {
    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(FragmentA.KEY, parcelableObject);
    bundle.putLong(FragmentA.KEY, objectID);
    fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentA);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

In `FragmentA` I need to use the selected custom `Parcelable` object so I get it in `onCreate` from the `bundle` like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    currentObject = bundle.getParcelable(KEY);
    objectID = bundle.getLong(KEY);

    ...
}
```

Note: currentObject is a private `CustomParcelable` defined in the `fragment`, objectID is a private long defined in the `fragment`, KEY is `public final string` defined in the `fragment`.

When I later use currentObject in one of my methods it returns NPE because currentObject is null. When debugging it shows that it gets the `Parcelable`, but with the value of objectID.

[image: Is the data passed cor]Is the data passed correctly? What exactly causes currentObject to be null?

Comment: WHY are you using same key for both datas? Use different keys for both datas

Comment: Should I use a different key? If yes, why so?

Comment: because in bundle we use key value pair scheme so for two different values you should use two keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use different key for each data. because the bundle element is treated name value pairs, one key and corresponding value,

What have you done is used same key for both data, so the first data got over written by the second long data,

for example if you see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelable) it is stated that for `putParcelable`

> Inserts a Parcelable value into the mapping of this Bundle, replacing any existing value for the given key. Either key or value may be null.

What you should be doing is

```
public void openFragment(CustomParcelable parcelableObject, long objectID) {
    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(FragmentA.KEY1, parcelableObject);
    bundle.putLong(FragmentA.KEY2, objectID);
    fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentA);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

and in fragmentA

```
currentObject = bundle.getParcelable(KEY1);
objectID = bundle.getLong(KEY2);
```

Hope this clears your doubt

Comment: I see what I did wrong. Thank you for the help, it works fine now.